# 2-D Kalman Filtering in Python using Numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I am practicing Kalman filtering and wrote a short python class that uses Numpy to calculate the 2-D kalman filter for position and velocity along the X axis: assume that the object is only moving along the X-axis since it's on a flat ground.

The following code is syntactically correct and when executed looks like functionally correct.  The printed distance approaches the measured distance, since in the loop, it's assumed the object is stationary.

Please have a look at the below and let me know if it's the correct implementation of a 2-D kalman filter?

*note* I have set process errors and observation errors to *zero* for now.

```
import numpy as np


class KalmanFilter(object):

    def __init__(self, delta_t,
                 initial_position,
                 initial_velocity,
                 acceleration,
                 calc_error_in_position,
                 calc_error_in_velocity,
                 obs_error_in_position,
                 obs_error_in_velocity):

        self.obs_Error = 0.
        self.w = 0.
        self.q = 0.

        self.I = np.array([[1, 0], [0, 1]])
        self.A = np.array([[1, delta_t], [0, 1]])
        self.B = np.array([[.5 * (delta_t**2), delta_t]])

        self.previous_state = np.array(
            [[initial_position], [initial_velocity]])
        self.predicted_state = self._calculate_predicted_state(acceleration)

        self.measured_state = np.zeros((2, 1))

        self.previous_P = np.array([
            [calc_error_in_position**2,
                (calc_error_in_position * calc_error_in_velocity)],
            [(calc_error_in_position * calc_error_in_velocity),
             calc_error_in_velocity**2]
        ])

        self.R = np.array([
            [obs_error_in_position**2,
                (obs_error_in_position * obs_error_in_velocity)],
            [(obs_error_in_position * obs_error_in_velocity), obs_error_in_velocity**2]
        ])



    def _adjust_measured_observation(self, observed_position, observed_velocity):
        obs_X = np.array([[observed_position], [observed_velocity]])
        self.observed_state = self.I * obs_X + self.obs_Error

    def _calculate_predicted_state(self, acceleration):
        self.predicted_state = (
            self.A * self.previous_state) + (self.B * acceleration) + self.w

    def _calculate_predicted_covariance(self):
        self.P = (self.A * self.previous_P * self.A.T) + self.q

    def _update_predicted_convariance(self):
        self.previous_P = np.array(
            (self.I - (self.kalman_gain * self.I)) * self.P)

    def _calculate_kalman_gain(self):
        self.kalman_gain = (self.P * self.I.T) / \
            ((self.I * self.P * self.I.T) + self.R)

    def _calculate_current_position(self):
        self.current_state = self.previous_state + \
            (self.kalman_gain * (self.observed_state - (self.I * self.previous_state)))
        self.previous_state = np.array(self.current_state)

    def get_current_position(self, observed_position, observed_velocity, acceleration):
        self._calculate_predicted_state(acceleration)
        self._calculate_predicted_covariance()
        self._calculate_kalman_gain()
        self._adjust_measured_observation(observed_position, observed_velocity)
        self._calculate_current_position()
        self._update_predicted_convariance()

        return self.previous_state[0][0]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    kf = KalmanFilter(1, 1.5, .5, .1, .3, .4, .3, .8)
    for i in range(20):
        print(kf.get_current_position(2.5, .8, .1))
```